# How to redirect stderr and stdout in distinct files in Jetty?

Tags: logging, jetty

Almost everything is in the title, my configuration file for the logging in jetty looks like this:

A Gist of the config file is available there -> https://gist.github.com/3145564

My problem is that everything goes to the file where stderr is redirected, info logs, warning logs, and nothing goes to the file where the sdtout stream is redirected.

Thank you for your help, really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jetty has crude logging by default because we can't really make assumptions was to what logging frameworks anyone will use.  However we have it set up so that all you need to do is drop in the slf4j-api jar into the classpath and we'll start using that and from there you can redirect your logging however you like.

see this for basic information: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Logging

you can look for a nice fine grained example of sifting logs based on webapps here:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Sifting_Logs_with_Logback

So while jetty logging looks rough right out of the box, it has to be that way to not cause problems with any user logging framework since jetty is used in so many different ways, embedded, as as distribution, on devices like android, etc etc.  We do have a nice simple way to give you all the control you need via this slf4j setup.

Comment: Ok thanks, so I tried with Logback with the tutorial you give me, but I can't see a way to split logs into 2 files one with info,warning logs and another with error logs. On my understanding the only thing I can do is split logs based on packages. For the level it seems I can only set the minimum level and not the top level log. Am I right? or I misunderstand something?

Comment: I found happiness with "Filters"(http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html) thanks again Jesse.